# Never lose the focus of the main tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

How can I always set the focus of the main tab so in case that it opens a new one this one always be opened and never lose the elements in it?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Edgar S.

```
        main_window = driver.window_handles[0]

        for i in range(4, len(rows)):
            ic(range(4, len(rows)))
            row = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")[i]
            ic(row)
            cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
            ic(cells)
            image_elements = cells[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
            ic(image_elements)
            if image_elements:
                    image_to_click = image_elements[0]
                    ic(image_to_click)
                    #image_to_click.click()
```

But always loses the focus because it downloads a file in a new tab and whe it tries to access the second element it is failing and displayin an error message, that the element is not available anymore.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the driver will never switch to another tab unless you explicitly tell it to.  You should include the error in your post,

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is get the handle for the original tab, and then explictly switch back to it after clicking to download an image.

```
main_window = driver.current_window_handle


for i in range(4, len(rows)):
    ic(range(4, len(rows)))
    row = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")[i]
    ic(row)
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    ic(cells)
    image_elements = cells[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
    ic(image_elements)
    if image_elements:
            image_to_click = image_elements[0]
            ic(image_to_click)
            #image_to_click.click()
    driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```